# How can I prove that for any n≥1, n points can be found in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that in the d metric, the distance between any two points equals 1?

Tags: real-analysis

$\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is defined as the set of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. 
For any $f,g \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$, a metric is defined as:

$$d(f, g) = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$$

Prove that for any $n \geq 1$, $n$ points can be found in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that in the $d$ metric, the distance between any two points equals $1$.

Here's where my problem is: I do not understand how points can be found in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ as it applies to the metric. If it were the distances between functions being discussed, I might have some further understanding. An induction proof seems to be the way to go, but I really don't even comprehend entirely what is going on so my starting grounds are pretty unstable.

I'm not exactly looking for a word for word proof, I would just like someone to educate me a bit more on this topic so I can at least understand what is going on.

Comment: "Points" in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ are functions, and you're being asked to find a collection $f_1, \cdots, f_n \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that $d(f_i, f_j) = 1$ for all $i$, $j$, or equivalently, such that $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_i (x) - f_j (x)| = 1$ for all $i, j$. Does that help?

Comment: @SameerKailasa Yes that does help quite a bit, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint - [these three functions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h0bcfouxft) have distance 1 from each other.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want $n$ continuous
functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ on $[0,1]$, such that $\|f_i-f_j\|_\infty
=\sup|f_i(x)-f_j(x)|=1$ for all $i\ne j$.

Insisting that each $f_i$ takes values in the interval $[0,1]$ will
ensure that $\|f_i-f_j\|_\infty\le1$. To enforce $\|f_i-f_j\|_\infty=1$
pick some point $a_{i,j}\in[0,1]$ and choose $f_i$ and $f_j$
such that $f_i(a_{i,j})=1$ and $f_j(a_{i,j})=0$.
One has to do this for all $i$ and $j$ at the same time, but that should
be possible as there are only finitely many pairs $(i,j)$ to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Any $n$ functions with norm $1$ and disjoint supports will do. Just take continuous functions $\{f_i\}$ with support in $(\frac i n-\frac  1 {n^{2}},\frac i n-\frac  1 {n^{2}})$ so that $\|f_i\|=1$ for all $i$

Answer (score 0):

We can do more.

In the usual notation, $\|f\|=\max \{|f(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}$ for $f\in C[0,1].$

There is a countably infinite $S\subset C[0,1]$ such that $\forall f\in S\,(\|f\|=1/2)$ and such that for all distinct $f,g \in S$ we have $d(f,g)=1.$

For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f_n\in C[0,1]$ such that (i) $\|f_n\|=1/2$ and (ii) $f_n(1/n)=1/2$ and (iii) $f_n(x)=-1/2 $ for all $x\in [0,1/(n+1)].$

Let $S=\{f_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$

Let $m,n\in \Bbb N$ with $m<n.$ Then $f_m(1/n)=-1/2$ but $f_n(1/n)=1/2$ so $$d(f_m,f_n)\ge |f_m(1/n)-f_n(1/n)|=1.$$  And $$d(f_m,f_n)\le \|f_m\|+\|f_n\|=1.$$ So $d(f_m,f_n)=1.$

Comment: More generally, in $C[0,1],$ if $D$ is a closed ball of radius $r>0$ then $D$ has an infinite subset $S$ such  that $d(f,g)=2r$ for all distinct $f,g \in S$, so $D$ is not compact. For more on compact subsets of $C[0,1]$, see the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem.